# Windows forms full screen resolution

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I started working on a project in Windows Forms, and I want to set my main Form to full screen, and start adding control on it. The problem is that, after I set the Form to FullScreen with

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

the main form is indeed set to FullScreen, but it remains at the original resolution in Visual Studio IDE. So I tried to get the Form resolution when in Full Screen with this piece of code

```
int h = Size.Height;
int w = Size.Width;

label1.Text = h.ToString() + " " + w.ToString();
```

and it indeed returns the resolution of the Form at that moment (1379 x 718) but the main problem is that when I set the Form resolution in IDE to that of the returned code above and then try to place a Control at let's say Position.X = 1300, it will show it halfway across the screen in the main program. It seems that the problem is a Form resolution at FullScreen different than the resolution at which I can place Controls.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the properties Dock and Anchor. Study how they work

Comment: I saw the documentation on Dock and Anchor, but it seems that the Visual Studio IDE resolution and when the program is running resolution doesn't seems to match, and I don't really know why.